# Transform recursive method into non-recursive C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, recurrence

I'm struggling with dynamic programming and desperately need help! I would very appreciate it. For hours I've been trying to transform a recursive method into a non-recursive one, but was unable to do that. My initial task was to write two algorithms for a recurrent equation. The first method being a recursive method, the other using a loop and storing the data.

> There are two integers, **n** and w, and two integer arrays s[**n**] and p[**n**]. Need to find the return value of a recursive method G1(**n**, w) then create method G2(**n**, w) which would complete the same task, but it has to use loops instead of recursion.

```
    private static int G1(int k, int r)
    {
        if (k == 0 || r == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (s[k - 1] > r)
        {
            return G1(k - 1, r);
        }

        return Max(G1(k - 1, r), p[k - 1] + G1(k - 1, r - s[k - 1]));
    }
```

I found a possible solution for C#, but I couldn't apply it for my equation:

[A similar task (RECURSION)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXf6Y.png)

[A similar task (LOOP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko2T7.png)

This is my code and initial data, but I can't get it to work:

```
    n = 3;
    w = 3;

    s = new List<int>{ 2, 3, 8 };
    p = new List<int> { 1, 3, 5 };

    private static int G2(int k, int r)
    {
        List<Tuple<int, int, int>> data = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
        data.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(0, 0, 0));

        do
        {
            if (data[0].Item1 == 0 || data[0].Item2 == 0)
            {
                data[0] = new Tuple<int, int, int>(data[0].Item1, data[0].Item2, 0);
            }

            else 
            {
                if (s[data[0].Item1 - 1] > data[0].Item2)
                {
                    data.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(data[0].Item1 - 1, data[0].Item2, data[0].Item3));
                }

                if (data[0].Item1 + 1 >= k)
                {
                    data.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(data[0].Item1 - 1, data[0].Item2, data[0].Item3));
                }

                if (data[0].Item2 + 1 >= r)
                {
                    data.Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(data[0].Item1 - 1, data[0].Item2 - s[data[0].Item1 - 1], data[0].Item3 + p[data[0].Item1 - 1]));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"DEBUG: current k: {data[0].Item1} current r: {data[0].Item2} current result: {data[0].Item3}");
            data.RemoveAt(0);

        } while (data.Count > 0 && data.Count(entry => entry.Item1 == k && entry.Item2 == r) <= 0);


        return data.First(entry => entry.Item1 == k && entry.Item2 == r).Item3;
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid I can't go into the intricacies of your algorithm - it looks enough to induce a very painful migraine! But, generally speaking, when you need to have recursive-like behaviour without actually recursing you end up using a stack to push data on to and then keep popping it off until you're done. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In the second piece of code you posted, you initialize the **data** collection with a **(0,0,0) entry**, so as soon as it enters the loop it goes inside the first **If** condition which afterwards jumps to the **Console.WriteLine()** instruction where you **remove the first entry** thus leaving the collection **empty** which causes to exit the **while** loop condition. the return code will thus give an exception as there is no **First()** item to fetch. Is this intended?

Comment: Why have you called this "dynamic programming"?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I was wondering the same thing, but the tag description matches the question: `Dynamic programming is an algorithmic technique for efficiently solving problems with a recursive structure containing many overlapping subproblems.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common solution. You should create a 2D arry by the size of `k x r`. Then, loop on this array in diagonal zigzag order to fill the value (in bottom-up order, like the following image).

[image]

At the end of the filling the value of the 2d array, you will have the value of `G2(k,r)`. You can find the implementation of `G2(k,r)` in the below.

```
int G2(int k, int r)
{
    int[,] values = new int[k + 1,r + 1];
    var maxDim = Max(k + 1,r + 1);
    for( int h = 1 ; h < maxDim * 2 ; h++ ) {
        for( int j = 0 ; j <= h ; j++ ) {
            int i = h - j;
            if( i <= k && j <= r && i > 0 && j > 0 ) {
                if (s[i - 1] > j)
                {
                     values[i,j] = values[i - 1, j];
                }
                else
                {
                     values[i,j] = Max(values[i - 1, j], p[i - 1] + values[i - 1, j - s[i - 1]]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return values[k , r];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but the code throws an index out of bounds error.

Comment: This problem might come from your `s` and `p` array size. Their size must be `k+1` and `r+1`, respectively.

Comment: int i = h - j; adding + 1 to this line has solved the issue, the results of the G1 and G2 seem to match, thanks! I'll do some more testing before I mark this as the solution.

Comment: ya. You're right. as if `i` less than `1`, for `s[i-1]` get index out of the range. So, the solution is updated.